# PHPUnit LogicException: The request was not redirected. Symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am trying to test a simple registration with phpunit with a redirect, I have all the time this error:

[image]

Test class:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class SecuriteTest extends WebTestCase
{

    private $user;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->user = static::createClient();
    }

    public function testsendCreateAccountMail(){

        $crawler = $this->user->request('GET', '/inscription');

        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Informations personnelles")')->count());

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('submitInscription')->form();

        $form['inscription[gender]']     = 'Masculin';
        $form['inscription[name]']       = 'Test';
        $form['inscription[firstName]']      = 'Test';
        $form['inscription[username]']    = 'Test-25@gmail.com';
        $form['inscription[birthDate]']    =  '05/10/1992';
        $form['inscription[pseudo]']    = 'Test';
        $form['inscription[password][first]']    = 'blablabla';
        $form['inscription[password][second]']    = 'blablabla';
        $form['inscription[account]']    = 'Particulier';
        $form['inscription[mentionsLegales]']    = '1';

        $this->user->submit($form);

        $crawler = $this->user->followRedirect();

        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('.testFlash:contains("Vous allez recevoir une demande de confirmation sur votre adresse email")')->count());

    }
}
```

I also try to test with a contact form with only 3 inputs, I still have the same error.

Thank you

Comment: I guess that the response (after form submit) didn't have 30X http code, so it's not really a redirect response. Therefore `followRedirect();` is throwing that exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to add more test about every aspect of the flow as example the http communication's status. As example you can add after every server interaction that the request was fine:

```
    $crawler = $this->user->request('GET', '/inscription');
    // check server response:
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());
    // or more simply:
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    // then check the response content
    $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Informations personnelles")')->count());
```

In the same manner, before follow redirection test that the post work fine and don't give an error like 500:

```
    $this->user->submit($form);
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirection());
    $crawler = $this->user->followRedirect();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, now the redirection works but I have a problem for the last assertEquals with filter. Flashbag message (last line of code), (Failed asserting that false is true.), I put exactly the same message.